# php print a page bring up printer list

Tags: php

How do you bring up the printer list when you print a page in php?  I've got the following code but is not bringing up the list of printers found on the pc.

```
echo "<a href='http://xxx/printme.php?$key' target='_blank' media='print'>Print Now</a>";
```

Comment: Are you trying to list printers installed on the user's computer?

Comment: I don't know much, but I think your question is html related, not php. (Or maybe just browser related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Javascript `window.print()` in an `onclick` event on your `<a>`

You can only print the current page.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with PHP. You need JavaScript for this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">
```